# How to get closest date for specific rows in postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, select

I have the following problem:

I have a table containing two types of data. One with state = 1 and one with state = 2. For every row with state = 2 I need the last corresponding date with state = 1. Here's an example:

```
date           state    id
'2016-04-03'   1        1
'2016-04-04'   1        1
'2016-04-05'   2        1
'2016-04-06'   2        1
```

Expected result:

```
date           lastdate       state    id
'2016-04-03'   '2016-04-03'   1        1
'2016-04-04'   '2016-04-04'   1        1
'2016-04-05'   '2016-04-04'   2        1
'2016-04-06'   '2016-04-04'   2        1
'2016-04-07'   '2016-04-07'   1        1
```

I don't exactly know where I am stuck. It feels like this problems you're looking at the wrong way so any help is appreciated.

Thx in advance!

**Edit**

As it seems like I didn't explain my problem good enough, here's another try:

For every row I need the date of the last row with the same id which had state = 1. If the state is already 1 the date of the same row is needed.

So to clarify my "expected results" - Table:

```
date           lastdate       state    id
'2016-04-03'   '2016-04-03'   1        1
```

state is 1 so date of row is last date with state 1

```
'2016-04-04'   '2016-04-04'   1        1
```

state is 1 so date of row is last date with state 1

```
'2016-04-05'   '2016-04-04'   2        1
```

state is 2 so date of the last row with date 1 is from the row before

```
'2016-04-06'   '2016-04-04'   2        1
```

state is 2, last date with state = 1 is '2016-04-04'

```
'2016-04-07'   '2016-04-07'   1        1
```

state is 1 again, so same date

```
'2016-04-08'    '2016-04-07'  2        1
```

state is 2, so date of last row (row before) is set

I hope my intentions are understandable now.

Comment: please try to clarify what you really want. Your description of what you want and your example given seem to be totally different.

Comment: Tried my best to do so ;-)

Comment: ok, now i understand what you want.. I'm not totally sure this is possible only with sql but i'll think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by joining a table with itself:

```
select distinct on (a.date) 
    a.date date, 
    coalesce(b.date, a.date) last_date, 
    a.state, 
    a.id
from test a
left join test b 
on a.state = 2 and b.state = 1 and b.date < a.date
order by a.date, b.date desc;

    date    | last_date  | state | id 
------------+------------+-------+----
 2016-04-03 | 2016-04-03 |     1 |  1
 2016-04-04 | 2016-04-04 |     1 |  1
 2016-04-05 | 2016-04-04 |     2 |  1
 2016-04-06 | 2016-04-04 |     2 |  1
 2016-04-07 | 2016-04-07 |     1 |  1
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Thx a lot! I was so close. For some reason I was stuck on the idea of an inner join and therefore the result was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like  this (I'm not sure everything in the syntax is correct):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dates() RETURNS TABLE (date DATE, lastdate DATE,
state INTEGER, id INTEGER) AS $$
DECLARE
   lastType1 DATE;
BEGIN
   FOR d IN (SELECT * FROM tableName)
   LOOP
       IF d.state == 1 THEN
            lastType1 = d.date;
       END IF;
       RETURN NEXT (d.date, lastType1, d.state, d.id);
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
END
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This you can call by `SELECT * FROM dates()`, if you want to access it like a table i would recommend creating a view calling the function

You just have to put instead of `dates()` what you want to call your function and instead of `tableName`what you table is actually called

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
select t1.date as date, (
    select  date
        from mytable where state = 1 and t1.date::date - date::date >= 0 order by t1.date::date - date::date  limit 1
    ) as last_date
,t1.state , t1.id from mytable t1 where state = 2
```

Comment: Thank you. Also an interesting way to solve the problem.